# make a loop parallel

Tags: linux, shell, parallelism

How to make this loop parallel :

```
for a in $(seq 1 3)
do
  for b in 0.1 0.2 
  do
    echo process with a=$a and b=$b &
  done
done
```

is it in parallel or not ? 
In fact, I want to run the instruction `echo process with a=$a and b=$b` in parallel for each combination of the values `a` and `b`
Here is the result of runing the above shell :

```
process with a=1 and b=0.1
process with a=2 and b=0.2
process with a=2 and b=0.1
process with a=3 and b=0.2
process with a=3 and b=0.1
process with a=1 and b=0.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the output appears nondeterministic should already suffice to demonstrate that the background jobs run in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel echo process with a={1} and b={2} ::: 1 2 3 ::: 0.1 0.2 
seq 1 3 | parallel echo process with a={1} and b={2} :::: - ::: 0.1 
parallel echo process with a={1} and b={2} :::: <(seq 1 3) ::: 0.1 0.2
```

I assume `echo` is just an example, as parallelizing `echo` is hardly worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you run in the inner loop takes any amount of time (an `echo` is *very quick* to run), then, when the loops have started all the asynchronous processes, they will be running *concurrently*.

The loops themselves are not "parallel".

Answer (score 0):

This should have be a comment, but comments are too small.

Make sure your solution works for output of arbitrary sizes and does not mix output from one job with another. Here is a small example to test that:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                               

# stress test of parallelizing programs                                                   

longline() {
    # print one big line with 'a's followed by 'b's followed by 'c's                      
    perl -e 'print "@ARGV ", map { "$_"x10000000 } (a..c)' "$@"
    echo
}


echo "Run testprogram in parallel"
for a in $(seq 1 3)
do
    for b in 0.1 0.2
    do
        longline $a $b &
    done
done |
# use 'tr' to compress many 'a's into a single 'a'                                        
# if the output is not 'abc' on every line, lines have been mixed                         
  tr -cs '@'

echo "Run testprogram in serial"
for a in $(seq 1 3)
do
    for b in 0.1 0.2
    do
        longline $a $b
    done
done | tr -cs '@'


echo "Compare with GNU Parallel"
export -f longline
parallel -kj0 longline :::: <(seq 1 3) ::: 0.1 0.2 | tr -cs '@'
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the response in your exemple, I'd try it :)